# Need to get rid of single quote character (') in MATLAB string array

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string array in MATLAB '''''''xxxxx''''''', and I want only xxxxx. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
s='''''''xxxxx''''''';
newS = strrep(s, '''', '');

newS =

xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need a lot of quotes to represent just one!
Here is the code to remove all quotes:

```
x(x=='''')=[]
```